# Is there a way to validate AnalyticsService prior to querying data

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I have the following method that returns `AnalyticsService` after it authenticates a Google Developer service account.

```
public static AnalyticsService AuthenticateUsingServiceAccount(string keyfilePath, string serviceAccountEmail)
{
    if (serviceAccountEmail == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceAccountEmail", "serviceAccountEmail cannot be a null reference");
    if (keyfilePath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keyfilePath", "keyfilePath cannot be a null reference");


    if (!File.Exists(keyfilePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Keyfile does not exist");
    }

    string[] scopes = new string[]
    {
        AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics, // view and manage your analytics data
        AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit, // edit management actives
        AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers, // manage users
        AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly
    }; // View analytics data       

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyfilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = scopes
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "My analytics service",
    });

    return service;
}
```

Is there a way to validate `service` (make sure it has been initialized using a correct keyfile and a correct service account email) before returning it? Knowing that `new AnalyticsService` will always return a `service` object whether the input parameters are correct or not.

The current behavior is that, if the parameters (credential) are not correct, the `service` will then throw exception only after calling an API, and for me, that is a bit late.